# Routing with Angular 2 and EpiServer

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, episerver

Is it possible for Angular 2 to ignore whatever comes before a route/path? I'm using Angular 2 on my EpiServer website. When I press a link using Angular, it removes whatever path that comes before it.

For example:

- User navigates to `/jobs/application/step1`.
- He or she performs some action on the page, then presses a button to go to `/jobs/application/step2`.
- Angular then removes `/jobs/application/` from the path and the url becomes `/step2`.

Is it possible for Angular to continue using the current path and put the step 2 path on `/jobs/application/step2`?

Comment: So your Angular app runs relative inside /step1? If so, you could set the base href in the head of the index.html of your angular app (that one that contains the angular scripts and boot element) <base href="/jobs/application/">

Comment: <base href="path/path/"> ended up being exactly what i needed! Thanks for the suggestion mate :-)